# Why won't images display on Logitech device?

Tags: gridview, imageview, android, logitech

I'm running an app that pulls images using a URL into a gridView, the app runs fine on the emulator, but when I run it on the Logitech device the images are not displayed. Instead only the stub thumbnail is shown.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

//intialize variables

public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

Context mContext;
private List<Video> myVideos;

/*
 * Constructor
 * @params: Context
 * @params: XML url
 */
public ImageAdapter(Context a,List<Video> myList){
    mContext = a; 
    myVideos = myList;          
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(mContext);
}

/*s
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageView view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view= new ImageView(mContext);
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,150));
        view.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);               
    }
    else{
        view = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
   Log.i("Assigning view","");
   imageLoader.DisplayImage(myVideos.get(position).getThumbNail(), view);   
   return view;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
 */
public int getCount() {
    return myVideos.size();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
 */
public String getItem(int position) {
    return myVideos.get(position).toString();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

```
public class MemoryCache {

private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
private long size=0;//current allocated size
private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

public MemoryCache(){
    //use 25% of available heap size
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
}

public void setLimit(long new_limit){
    limit=new_limit;
    Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
}

public Bitmap get(String id){
    if(!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    return cache.get(id);
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        if(cache.containsKey(id))
            size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    }catch(Throwable th){
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkSize() {
    Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
    if(size>limit){
        Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
            size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if(size<=limit)
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
    }
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}

long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap==null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My MemoryCache class was referencing and external storage that did not exist on the logitech Device